# how to make a rolling mean in pandas but only for items that have the same id/value?

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

```
columns: datetime | clientid | amounts | *new_column_to_be_implemented* (rolling mean of values before but only for values that are the same in clientid)
```

```
          `day 1` |    2     |  50     |  (na)
          `day 2` |    2     |  60     |  50
          `day 3` |    1     |  45     |  (na)
          `day 4` |    2     |  45     |  110
          `day 5` |    3     |  90     |  (na)
          `day 6` |    3     |  10     |  90
          `day 7` |    2     |  10     |  105
```

1. so this gets the mean of the last 2 amounts of the same clientid for example.
2. I know it is possible to add a list and append/pop values to remember them, but is there a better way in pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure to following the guidelines described in [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) when asking `pandas` related questions, it helps a lot for reproducibility.

The key element for the answer is the pairing of the `groupby` and `rolling` methods. `groupby` will group all the records with the same `clientid` and `rolling` will select the correct amount of records for the mean calculation.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setting up the dataframe
data = [
          ['day 1', 2, 50],
          ['day 2', 2, 60],
          ['day 3', 1, 45],
          ['day 4', 2, 45],
          ['day 5', 3, 90],
          ['day 6', 3, 10],
          ['day 7', 2, 10]
]

columns = ['date', 'clientid', 'amounts']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

rolling_mean = df.groupby('clientid').rolling(2)['amounts'].mean()
rolling_mean.index = rolling_mean.index.get_level_values(1)

df['client_rolling_mean'] = rolling_mean
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I will follow the guidelines in future questions!

Comment: one last question the rolling_mean.index.get_level_values(1) part is it to reset the index as it was? so it isn't grouped anymore? or is there more to it?

Comment: @BernarvanTongeren indeed, after the successive `groupby` and `rolling` we have a `MultiIndex` corresponding to `(clientid, old_index)`, the `get_level_values` accesses the `old_index`

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark my response as 'Answer'